# Como validar senha através do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um formulário que eu preciso confirmar se os campos, NovaSenha e o CNovaSenha, são iguais.
Só se os dois campos forem iguais que o sistema vai permitir da post para o arquivo troca_senha.php
Se puder ser com o jquery, é melhor ainda.
Aceito sugestões.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Reset de Senha</title>
    <script>
                function validarSenha()
                    NovaSenha = document.FormSenha.NovaSenha.value;
                    NovaSenha = document.FormSenha.CNovaSenha.value;

                    if (NovaSenha != CNovaSenha) 
                        alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES!\\nFAVOR DIGITAR SENHAS IGUAIS");
            </script>
            </head>
        <body>

    <div class="container-fluid container_reset">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="well">
                        <form action="troca_senha.php" method="POST" id="FormSenha" name="FormSenha">
                            <div class="centraliza_reset">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="span2"></div>
                                    <div class="span3">Nova Senha:</div>
                                    <div class="span6"><input type="password" maxlength="10" name="NovaSenha" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="span2"></div>
                                    <div class="span3">Confirme a nova Senha:</div>
                                    <div class="span6"><input type="password" maxlength="10" name="CNovaSenha" /></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary pull-left botao_limpar_senha">Limpar</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right botao_reset_senha" onClick="validarSenha()">Enviar</button>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu código está correto!

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Reset de Senha</title>
    <script>
function validarSenha(){
   NovaSenha = document.getElementById('NovaSenha').value;
   CNovaSenha = document.getElementById('CNovaSenha').value;
   if (NovaSenha != CNovaSenha) {
      alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES!\nFAVOR DIGITAR SENHAS IGUAIS"); 
   }else{
      document.FormSenha.submit();
   }
}
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>

<div class="container-fluid container_reset">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="well">
                    <form action="troca_senha.php" method="POST" id="FormSenha" name="FormSenha">
                        <div class="centraliza_reset">
                            <fieldset>
                                <br /><br />
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="span2"></div>
                                <div class="span3">Nova Senha:</div>
                                <div class="span6"><input type="password" maxlength="10" id="NovaSenha" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="span2"></div>
                                <div class="span3">Confirme a nova Senha:</div>
                                <div class="span6"><input type="password" maxlength="10" id="CNovaSenha" /></div>
                                </div>

                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary pull-left botao_limpar_senha">Limpar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right botao_reset_senha" onClick="validarSenha()">Enviar</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

O único erro que encontrei foi que você estava armazenando outro valor na mesma variável, e fazendo o teste com outra variável

**----- EDITADO------**

Recomendo utilizar id em vez de name, fica mais fácil recuperar o valor np backend...

Comment: Testei os dois exemplos e não está funcionando.
Eu digitei 123 e 456 no segundo campo e deu submit mesmo assim.
Seria por uma questão de posição do código?

Comment: pronto, editei o código

Comment: Obrigado.
Deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

Adicione no `Form` o `onsubmit`: `onsubmit="return validarSenha();"`

```
<form action="troca_senha.php" method="POST" id="FormSenha" name="FormSenha" onsubmit="return validarSenha();">
```

Modifique o `type` do `button` para `Submit`:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right botao_reset_senha">Enviar</button>
```

E então na função `JavaScript`:

```
 function validarSenha(){
        NovaSenha = document.FormSenha.NovaSenha.value;
        CNovaSenha = document.FormSenha.CNovaSenha.value;
        if (NovaSenha != CNovaSenha){ 
             alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES!\\nFAVOR DIGITAR SENHAS IGUAIS");
             return false;
        }
        return true;
 }
```

Comment: @bfavaretto, verdade, sem necessidade. Retirei.